# Excel VBA - populating table from various workbooks via vlookup

Tags: vba, excel, lookup-tables, vlookup

Below in my code, there appears to be a problem with following line:

> `Range("B4").Formula = "=index(C5:AV51,1,column(ActiveCell)-2)"`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False

For Each Cell In Range("C6:AV51")
Range("B4").Formula = "=index(C5:AV51,1,column(ActiveCell)-2)"

    If ActiveCell.Row - ActiveCell.Column < 3 Then
        ActiveCell.Formula = "=vlookup(index(B5:AV51,row()-4,1),'[" & Range("B4").Value & ".xlsx]Sheet1'!A1:E70,4,false)"

    ElseIf ActiveCell.Row - ActiveCell.Column = 3 Then
        ActiveCell.Value = ""
    Else
        ActiveCell.Formula = "=vlookup(index(B5:AV51,row()-4,1),'[" & Range("B4").Value & ".xlsx]Sheet1'!A1:E70,5,false)"
    End If
Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

`ActiveCell` is an object, so replace all instances of

```
range("activecell")
```

with

```
ActiveCell
```

Example

```
if range("activecell").row - range("activecell").column < 3 then
```

becomes

```
if ActiveCell.row - ActiveCell.column < 3 then
```

another error, change:

```
range("B4").formula = "=index(C5:AV51,1,column("activecell")-2)"
```

to this

```
range("B4").formula = "=index(C5:AV51,1," & ActiveCell.Column & ")-2)"
```

Comment: Thanks, that's already improving my code a lot. However, I still got an error in this line 'else if ActiveCell.row - ActiveCell.column = 3 then'

Comment: Thanks, the code still doesn't work, however. I have updated it in my first post if you could take a look :)

Comment: Change `column(ActiveCell)` to `ActiveCell.Column` like I showed in my answer.  Note that its bad practice to update a question to completely change the context.  You should re-edit to restore the original question and add the new code as an update, so others can see how the answers address the question

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I will keep it in mind. I have implemented all suggested changes, however, it still doesn't appear to work; an error pops up stating "type mismatch" in following line `ActiveCell.Formula = "=vlookup(index(B5:AV51,row()-4,1),'[" & Range("B4").Value & ".xlsx]Sheet1'!A1:E70,4,false)"`